# Common file structure with flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-socketio

I'm building a flask app that retrieves data from a website, store the data on Flask-SQLAlchemy db and display the data. I wrote a script to do all of them but I've to run the files individually to achieve that.

my files structure:

```
-myapp
  database.py
  retrieve.py
  main.py
  templates
      --index.html
  static
      -css
        --style.css
      -js
        --script.js
```

database.py

```
from main import db, Session, User
from retrieve import git_api, DataTransform
session = Session()


def create_data():
     for row in df.iterrows():
          user = User(Issue_id=row[1]['Issue_id'],
                 Title= row[1]['Title'],
                 Description=row[1]['Description'],
                 State= row[1]['State'],
                 Assignee_name=row[1]['Assignee_name'],
                 Author_name = row[1]['Author_name'],
                 Created_at=row[1]['Created_at'][:10],
                 Updated_at=row[1]['Updated_at'][:10],
                 Closed_at= row[1]['Closed_at'],
                 Due_date=row[1]['Due_date'],
                 Issue_url= row[1]['Issue_url'])

         db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    git_api()
    df = DataTransform()
    create_data()
```

retrieve.py

```
import pandas as pd
import ssl
import requests

def git_api():
   //send a request and retrieve data
def def DataTransform():
  //transform data
  return df
```

main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates/layouts', static_folder='static')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
engine = create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False,autoflush=False))
db.init_app(app)



class User(db.Model):

    Issue_id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    Title = db.Column(db.String, index=True)
    Description = db.Column(db.String, index=True)
    State = db.Column(db.String(256))
    Assignee_name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    Author_name = db.Column(db.String(120))
    Created_at = db.Column(db.String(256))
    Updated_at = db.Column(db.String(20))
    Closed_at = db.Column(db.String(120))
    Due_date = db.Column(db.String(120))
    Issue_url = db.Column(db.String(120))


    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'Issue_id': self.Issue_id,
            'Title': self.Title,
            'Description': self.Description,
            'State': self.State,
            'Assignee_name': self.Assignee_name,
            'Author_name': self.Author_name,
            'Created_at': self.Created_at,
            'Updated_at': self.Updated_at,
            'Closed_at': self.Closed_at,
            'Due_date': self.Due_date,
            'Issue_url': self.Issue_url
        }

db.create_all()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('server_table.html')


@app.route('/api/data')
def data():
    query = User.query

    # search filter
    search = request.args.get('search[value]')
    if search:
        query = query.filter(db.or_(
            User.Title.like(f'%{search}%'),
            User.State.like(f'%{search}%'),
            User.Description.like(f'%{search}%')
        ))
    total_filtered = query.count()

    # sorting
    order = []
    i = 0
    while True:
        col_index = request.args.get(f'order[{i}][column]')
        if col_index is None:
            break
        col_name = request.args.get(f'columns[{col_index}][data]')
        if col_name not in ['Issue_id', 'Title', 'State', 'Assignee', 'Author_name']:
            col_name = 'Issue_id'
        descending = request.args.get(f'order[{i}][dir]') == 'desc'
        col = getattr(User, col_name)
        if descending:
            col = col.desc()
        order.append(col)
        i += 1
    if order:
        query = query.order_by(*order)

    # pagination
    start = request.args.get('start', type=int)
    length = request.args.get('length', type=int)
    query = query.offset(start).limit(length)

    # response
    return {
        'data': [user.to_dict() for user in query],
        'recordsFiltered': total_filtered,
        'recordsTotal': User.query.count()
    }



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

What I'm thinking to do is to structure the files and run the `database.py` every 5 minutes and update the db while the main.py is running but I'm new to python dev and I don't know how do it. Is there a simple or common way to achieve this? any pointers and suggestions would be great. thank you in advance for anyone who can help me!

Comment: Structure aside, you have an odd mix of plain `SQLAlchemy` and `flask_sqlalchemy`. Unless you're doing something unusual (and it looks like you aren't), letting`flask_sqlalchemy` handle engine and session details can simplify life.

Answer (score 2):

My directory structure approach to avoid circular imports in Flask
though you are free to create your own folder structure in flask in your own convenient way. This is the approach I use when the application grows and handling a lot of circular imports

```
.
├── app
│   ├── Auth
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── helpers.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── config.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── db
│   │   ├── database.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── models.py
│   ├── home
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── login
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── login.py
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   ├── style.css
│   │   │   └── style.css.map
│   │   ├── favicon_io
│   │   │   ├── android-chrome-192x192.png
│   │   │   ├── android-chrome-512x512.png
│   │   │   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
│   │   │   ├── favicon-16x16.png
│   │   │   ├── favicon-32x32.png
│   │   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   │   └── site.webmanifest
│   │   ├── images
│   │   │   └── avatar.png
│   │   └── scss
│   │       ├── forms.scss
│   │       ├── home.scss
│   │       ├── main.scss
│   │       ├── nav.scss
│   │       ├── profile.scss
│   │       └── reset.scss
│   └── templates
│       ├── auth
│       │   ├── blogs.html
│       │   ├── login.html
│       │   ├── profile.html
│       │   └── register.html
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── include
│       │   └── nav.html
│       └── index.html
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── test
│   └── __init__.py
└── wsgi.py
```

When you are using plain flask_sqlalchemy you have to db migrations on your own manually. So the best solution you can have is to integrate `flask-migrate` in your project which you just use to migrate the current changes you have made to your models

Here is how you add it
first you run `pip install flask-migrate` or `pipenv install flask-migrate` then import the `Migrate` class from the package and pass your flask app instance to it. This creates a singleton instance for the whole application.

##### `app/__init__.py`

```
"""App factrory file"""
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from app.config.config import APP_CONFIG
from app.db.database import db
from app.login.login import login_manager
from app.home.views import home as homeViews
from app.Auth.views import auth as authViews


def create_app():
    """App factory"""
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(APP_CONFIG["development"])
    db.init_app(app)
    Migrate(app,db)
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    # Register blueprint apps
    app.register_blueprint(homeViews)
    app.register_blueprint(authViews)

    return app
```

##### `app/db/database.py`

```
"""database.py"""
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


db = SQLAlchemy()
```

##### `app/db/models.py`

````
```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    ...


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
````

Afterwards you only need the `cli` to carry out the migrations

The manual way

```
(env) python
(env)>>> from app.db.database import db
(env)>>> from app import create_app
(env)>>> app=create_app()
(env)>>> app.app_context().push()
(env)>>> db.create_all()
(env)>>> exit()
```

The automated way

```
(env)>>> flask db init # When initializing the database to create initial migrations
(env)>>> flask db migrate -m "Initial tables creation" # On modified changes on the models with a commit message you can use for database rollback
(env)>>> flask db upgrade # Commit changes made to the models
(env)>>> flask run # Running the application

For subsequent changes you only need to run the

$ flask db migrate -m <your message>
$ flask_db upgrade
```